# Making Django Application localhost/appname Browsable through localhost

Tags: django, apache

My django application running on port 80 apache server and django, which I can browse by typing hxxp://localhost/myapp but i want it to directly browse by using hxxp://localhost. Where should i configure it to browse directly using localhost instead of typing localhost/myapp

xx=tt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all urls of your app are probably in your main urls.py or apps urls.py files.

Just edit the main urls.py file from:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
)
```

to

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('myapp.urls')),
)
```

You will have to handle all the urls in your myapp urls.py then...

Alan

Answer (score 1):

try from your project folder:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

it starts a very simple webserver running on port 8000 so you can see your site visiting

```
http://localhost:8000
```

To have more details see [django-admin.py and manage.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/)